# Compare two date components from different calendars

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I want to compare the "day" components of two NSDates. One of these dates were imported from a JSON file that contains dates in Persian Calendar format. The other one is the devices default NSDate().

Both the dates are pointing to the same day but one returns the day components different from the other one. When i log the day components they are different.

```
let cal2 = Calendar(identifier: .persian)
if cal2.dateComponents([.day,.month,.year], from: day as Date) == cal2.dateComponents([.day,.month,.year], from: date as Date)
{
   t = true
}
```

One of the dates is : 1395-07-20 (in persian calendar) and the other one is 2016-10-11. Both of these dates are equal and point to the same day.

Comment: "NSDate" is an absolute point in time and has no format, calendar, or "day" property. How exactly is the date formatted in the JSON, and how do you "import" it? – You could for example convert the date from JSON to NSDate using the Persian calendar, and the NSDate to NSDateComponents using the default calendar.

Comment: If you use 2 NSCalendars different (I mean Gregorian and Persian) on the same NSDate, it's normal that you don't have the same .day component.

Comment: @Hoa any solution?

Comment: @MartinR i am aware of that. thats why i asked this question! This is odd since NSDates are reference to an absolute value in time

Comment: You should at least show the input data, the code that you tried so far, and the actual and expected results.

Comment: @MartinR i just added the details

Comment: And how are `day` and `date` computed? – A *self-contained, reproducible* example makes it so much easier for others to reproduce your problem and suggest solutions.

Comment: date is the current date (Date) incremented by one day. The other one is from a core data entity that was populated by importing a list of JSON persian dates. The entity is of type NSDate.

Comment: I've added some code in an answer. Take a look. If your 2 NSDate point to same day, then using same Calendar to get components, you will have `t = true`.

Answer (score 2):

You should have 'true' in your console in this case:

```
//create 2 Date (from Persian calendar and from Gregorian calendar) that point to same day.
let componentPersian = NSDateComponents()
componentPersian.day = 20
componentPersian.month = 07
componentPersian.year = 1395
let date1 = persianCalendar?.dateFromComponents(componentPersian)

let componentGregorian = NSDateComponents()
componentGregorian.day = 11
componentGregorian.month = 10
componentGregorian.year = 2016
let date2 = gregorian?.dateFromComponents(componentGregorian)

//get NSDateComponents of those 2 Date, USING SAME CALENDAR. I use Gregorian in my test.
let components1 = gregorian?.components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: date1!)
let components2 = gregorian?.components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: date2!)

//and compare the values.
if (components1?.day == components2?.day
    && components1?.month == components2?.month
    && components1?.year == components2?.year
    ) {
    NSLog("true") //you must see this log in the console.
} else {
    NSLog("false")
}
```

Comment: Did not help, still the same thing. Did you try this yourself?

Comment: Call NSLog("date: \(YOUR_DATE_VARIABLE)") on your 2 Dates to see if they are same day or not.

Comment: It's actually weird, what i get from this piece of code is a date converted to string in persian calendar format!!!

let m = DateFormatter()
                m.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
                m.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
                let str = m.string(from: day as Date)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `DateFormatter` (see [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)) to convert the `Date` values to the same calendar format. After that, you can compare them.